# Rails3: how to disable automatic conversion of HTML tags?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How can I disable automatic conversion of HTML tags in Rails3? I have output in some controller view. For example I have method which outputs simple HTML link set..

```
[:en, :de].map{ |locale| link_to locate.to_s.upcase , { :locale => locate } ...
```

In view I'm calling my method `<%= my_method %>`

As a result I get this:

```
| &lt;a href=&quot;/login?class=language_selected&amp;amp;locale=en&quot;&gt;EN&lt;/a&gt;
```

How can I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't worked with Rails3 so no guarantees. but it looks like this has to do with the fact that your method returns a list.

Rails will usually format internal data structures for output by escaping the special characters and displaying the html escaped interpretation of your data.

Try tacking a .join onto the end of your map call to return a string

```
[:en, :de].map{ |locale| 
  link_to locate.to_s.upcase , { :locale => locate }
   ...
}.join("<br/>")
```

Also rwilliams aka r-dub's suggestion to use raw will probably be necessary addition to this code. raw on a list however may give you an undesirable result probably because of an internal `to_string` call. Which is an implicit join(""). So add the raw to the method call in addition to returning a string.

```
<%= raw my_method %>
```

Comment: If you're up voting for this, also toss an upvote for rwilliams aka-dub's solution. His/Her point about raw addresses the larger part of the root problem described in the question.

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure your methods output is safe then you can use the [raw](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper.html) method.

```
<%= raw my_method %>
```